# Get global string value in LLVM

Tags: c++, string, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I have situation where I have a function call in source with a constant string argument, and I want to access that string (as a CString or a char* or some such) inside the LLVM Pass in C++. 
Example of the source:

```
void some_function(){
    give_txt("abcd 1234");

}
```

The function

```
give_text
```

is a dummy function and is defined inside a .hpp -file as such:

```
const char* give_txt(char*)
{
    return ".";
}
```

So: **How do I access this "abcd 1234" inside the pass?**
I've gotten this far:

```
bool runOnModule(Module &M) override    
    {
        for(auto &F : M)
        {
                std::string name = F.getName();
                if(name.find("some_function") != std::string::npos)
                {
                        auto &B = *(F.begin());
                        for(auto &I : B)
                        {
                                if (auto* op = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&I))
                                {
                                        std::string mangled_name = op->getCalledFunction()->getName();
                                        std::string name = demangle(mangled_name);

                                        if(name.find("give_text") != std::string::npos)
                                        {
                                                Value* a = op->getArgOperand(0);
                                                auto a2 = op->arg_begin()->get();
                                                auto a3 = a->getType();
                                                auto a4 = dyn_cast<ConstantDataArray>(a);
                                                auto a5 = a4->getAsCString(); 

                                        }
```

But this clearly does not work, and the compilation crashes at the last instruction (assigning a5).

Comment: Why not iterate over `Module.globals()` instead to find your string constant?

Comment: How exactly? I can iterate over them but how do I discern which is the correct one and how do I get the string out of it?

Comment: @Elmore Seeing as this still doesn't have an accepted answer, did you figure out how to extract the string out of a `llvm::Constant` object? I am currently trying to achieve that, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, except `a4` and `a5` lines should be

```
auto a4 = dyn_cast<GlobalVariable>(a);
if (a4)
  auto a5 = dyn_cast<ConstantDataArray>(a4->getInitializer());
  if (a5)
    auto a6 = a5->getAsCString();
```